# Insert newline before 5 digits using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem: I have a .txt file which contains information in the following scheme:

```
ddddd name country time dddd name country time
```

The ddddd stands for 5 digits, representing the ID number of the participant. With available information I have come so far:

```
filename = 'raw_race.txt'
new_filename = 'data_race.txt'

pattern = re.compile(r'\D(\d{5})\D')

with open(filename, 'r') as readfile, open(new_filename, 'w+') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        writefile.write(line)
        if pattern.search(line):
            writefile.write('\n')
```

This does not work (output file is the same as input) and also, this would add the paragraph after the pattern, not before.

Does anyone see what I can do? Cheers!

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b(\d{5})\b', '\n\\1', line)` ?

Comment: `for line in readfile: writefile.write(re.sub(r'\b\d{5}\b', '\n\\g<0>', line))`

Comment: If the 5 digits are at the start of the string you could also use `pattern = re.compile(r'\d{5}\b')`  and use `if pattern.match(line):
            writefile.write('\n')`

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in readfile:
    writefile.write(re.sub(r'\b(\d{5})\b', '\n\\1', line))
```

did the trick, thank you!